# How to recover hard drive data hp dl380 after power supply burn?

Tags: windows-server-2012, hard-drive-recovery, recovery, hp-proliant

The power supply area is completly burn. How to retrieve data from the server now.

We have same server model, will it possible if i replace hard drives to another server?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: @caldeira if raid configuration is different?

Comment: You can access them drive by drive. Boot up the server and in the BIOS check if all of the HDs are showing up, then, you could boot a Live CD and retrieve your data.

Comment: Your question could be interpreted in a few different ways - please clarify if _"power supply area"_ refers to the actual PSU, the PSU's cables, the Molex headers, or the SATA power connector on each HDD.

Comment: The hardware is capable, but the licensing of the software may prove to be a genuine disadvantage :(